# Crystal Reports issue with ReportSelectionFormula

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have an issue where I need to run the following code to load a specific record from a database.  E.g

```
cryRpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Table.Column} = '1234'"
```

This works great, however I want to assign a variable at '1234', when running

```
cryRpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Table.Column} = '" & ArrayResult(0) & "'"
```

For some reason, the second apostrophe causes a line break and results in this and returns an error in the process

```
"{Table.Column} = '1234
'
```

Im unsure as to why this is occurring, I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: It says "The matching ' for this string is missing".  Due to the apostrophe on another line

Comment: I am not sure about crystal as a part of vb.net but I suspect instead of `ArrayResult(0)` use `ArrayResult[0]`.. not sure though... suggest to give a try

Comment: No luck, but yes I agree its got something to do with ArrayResult(0).

Comment: by comparing both try this "&"{Table.Column} = '" & ArrayResult(0) & "'"&"

Comment: Figured out the issue, the ArrayResult(0) actually had a line break but showed no visible signs of it.  Dumb mistake.  Performed a .Trim() on it and worked a treat.  Thank you for your help Siva.

Comment: Great... you were able to solve... happy coding